# What does fillMode do exactly?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

The documentation is not talking really much about what this technically does.

```
fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

I don't really see the effect of this. I have an view with alpha set to 0.0. Then I fade it in. But when I uncomment the line abouth, nothing changes. Same behavior. I'd like to understand what this fillMode really does.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [CAMediaTiming protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427656-fillmode):

> Determines if the receiver’s
> presentation is frozen or removed once
> its active duration has completed.

This determines what happens at the end of your animation.  By default, it is set to kCAFillModeRemoved, which means that the animation changes are undone when the animation is completed.  If you switch it to kCAFillModeForwards, the changes caused by the animation will hang around.

Note that you will also probably need to set the removedOnCompletion property to NO to prevent your animation from being removed, which would make this setting ineffective.

Comment: Great explanation! Yes, I have the removedOnCompletion set to NO. That's why I see no changes in the fillMode, right? Why is that called "fillMode"? So internally it's nothing more than keeping the new calculated parameters after all the animation interpolation routines?

Comment: So what's `removedOnCompletion` for if `fillMode` does the job?

Comment: @jowie - That prevents the animation as a whole from being removed on its completion. The fillMode merely locks it into its final state, but if it is set to be removed when done, the fillMode setting won't matter.

Comment: @BradLarson - so why have a `removedOnCompletion` option at all? I'm not sure why you need two parameters to basically do the same thing…

Comment: Will this still work, if I am changing the position of my layer? I don't think so. Doesn't matter what fillMode you have and wether removedOnCompletion has been set to NO. On animation end, the layer will be at its initial position. You won't be able to see this effect on simulator though. Use device.

Comment: @BradLarson I stumbled upon this post as I was searching for answer related to this. So, can you please tell me, why have both `removeOnCompletion` and `fillMode` when they seem to do the same thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @unheilig removeOnCompletion removes the animation from the layer when it has run to completion.  fillMode removes the EFFECT of the animation from the layer when it has run to completion.  If you set removeOnCompletion=false and leave fillMode set to remove, the animation will still exist (although stopped), but the effect will be reversed (the property will be set back to it's original value)

Comment: It has been changed to `CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards`

Answer (score 9):

let me give it a more clarified answer:
although in appearance setting the animation’s `fillMode` property to `kCAFillModeForwards`(or kCAFillModeBoth) and at the same time setting `removedOnCompletion` to `NO` can keep your layer in its final status when animation finished **but this use of `fillMode` is not the designed way**. and actually do harm if you have other animation add to the same the `keyPath`

(by the way,the correct approach for keep animation final state is to change the property value to match the final frame of the animation.)

what the `fillMode` **really use** is in connection with a child animation within a grouped animation so you can specify specific child animation in desired state