# Difference between kCAFillModeRemoved in CAMediaTiming and removedOnCompletion property of CAAnimation

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation

In apple's document, `kCAFillModeRemoved` in `CAMediaTiming` is : The receiver is removed from the presentation when the animation is completed.

`removedOnCompletion` property of `CAAnimation` is : Determines if the animation is removed from the target layer’s animations upon completion.

I know that if set `removedOnCompletion` to YES, the instance of CAAnimation will be removed when animation is complete. Now my question is that if set `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeRemoved`, what is removed when animation is complete.

Comment: This discussion is similar to what you're asking about [Fill mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166721/what-does-fillmode-do-exactly)!

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker I have seen that before, but It didn't say what kCAFillModeRemoved remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key word you are missing in those sentences is "presentation".

The `removedOnCompletion` property determines whether or not the animation object is removed from the layer upon completion.

The `fillMode` property determines the appearance of the presentation layer before and after the animation has passed (before beginTime and after beginTime+duration).

Example 1: `removed = NO` and `fillMode = removed` will look as if the animation is removed but it's not.

Example 2: `removed = YES` and `fillMode = forwards` the animation will be removed upon completion so there is nothing for the fill mode to fill in after the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I get the idea but still want to make it more clear. Does `fillMode` control the time when the presentation layer appears and disappears?

Comment: @KudoCC That's an interesting question. As far as I know, fillMode only fills in the values of the animation before the begin time and after completion (or both). It shouldn't have anything to do with when the presentation layer is either created or added. Simple logging of the presentationLayer before adding an animation, after adding an animation, before beginTime, during animation and after completion seems to support this. The same presentation layer was there all the time.

Comment: Let's say I want to change a layer's position using CABasicAnimation with `value1` as toValue. You said "fillMode fills in the values of the animation", what value does it fill in and which layer does it fill, the presentation layer or the other? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KudoCC Animations never touch the model layer. It's only the presentation layer (and the render server but you can't get to that one).